# Casting in member initializer list when passing variadic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a templated container class, which would internally use a byte array (for custom allocation reasons).

Something like this:

```
template<typename T, int size> class MyClass{

public:
    Byte internal_array[size * sizeof( T)];

    MyClass() = default;

    //...

};

//...

MyClass<int, 20> container;
```

If the internal one was a plain array, I could add a constructor that would allow for using list initialization.

```
template <typename...Args>
MyClass(Args&&...args) : internal_array{ std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

//...

MyClass<Byte, 2> container2 = { 1,2};
```

This only works with bytes though. The following is accepted by the compiler but gives garbage results:

```
MyClass<int, 2> container2 = { 1,2};
```

Can I somehow cast / reinterpret the internal array or the arguments in the constructor initialization so it works as intended?

Comment: A loop over the elements and placement-new at the correct "places" in the byte-array? Or take a look at how e.g. `std::vector` handles it, as it's usually implemented similarly (but with a dynamic "array" instead of a fixed-size one).

Comment: If your attempt doesn't work for you, please provide a [mcve]. In particular, don't omit details like the definition of `Byte`. It might very well be affecting your result without you being aware of it.

Comment: [std::uninitialized_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy) might help.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! Any idea how to use that with variadic arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::uninitialized_copy` and `std::initializer_list`, you might do something like:

```
template<typename T, int size> class MyClass
{
public:
    Byte internal_array[size * sizeof( T)];

    MyClass(std::initializer_list<T> ini)
    {
        std::uninitialized_copy(ini.begin(),
                                ini.end(),
                                reinterpret_cast<T*>(internal_array));
    }


    template <typename ... Ts>
    MyClass(Ts&& ... args) :
        MyClass(std::initializer_list<T>{T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)})
    {}

    //...

};
```

Comment: That uses [Delegate constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) constructing an `std::initializer_list` from the variadic argument.